# Asp.Net MVC 4.0 Model Localization With RegularExpression and ErrorMessage

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, resources

How to create my custom RegularExpressionValidator that gets the RegularExpression and ErrorMessage from Resource file?

```
 [RegularExpression(@"\d{5}(-\d{4})?",
          ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Global), ErrorMessageResourceName = "regExpValforPostal_ErrorMessage")]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The resource file name is Global :
>
> Global.resx, Global.zh.resx, Global.fr-ca.resx

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class LocalizedRegexAttribute : RegularExpressionAttribute
    {


        static LocalizedRegexAttribute()
        {
            // necessary to enable client side validation
            DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.RegisterAdapter(typeof(LocalizedRegexAttribute), typeof(RegularExpressionAttributeAdapter));
        }

        public LocalizedRegexAttribute(string _RegularExpression, string _ErrorMessageResourceName, Type _ErrorMessageResourceType)
            : base(LoadRegex(_RegularExpression))
        {
            ErrorMessageResourceType = _ErrorMessageResourceType;
            ErrorMessageResourceName = _ErrorMessageResourceName;

        }

        private static string LoadRegex(string key)
        {
            var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(typeof(Water.Localization.Resources.Global));
            return resourceManager.GetString(key);
        }
```

> In your model class you need to pass 3 parameters with the custom data
>   annotation as follows:

```
[LocalizedRegex("regExpValforPostal_ValidationExpression", "regExpValforPostal_ErrorMessage", typeof(Global))]
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you pass _ErrorMessageResourceType to LoadRegex like this

    private static string LoadRegex(Type resourceType, string key)

then you can use

    var resourceManager = new ResourceManager(resourceType)

and don't have to hard code the resource

Answer (score 2):

if your resources file called Validations.he.resx
and inside it you have both 'RegexExpression' and 'ErrorMessage' you should use this:

**UPDATE #1: Option 2 added**

- Option 1:

  > ```
  > public class LocalizedRegexAttribute :RegularExpressionAttribute
  > {
  >     public LocalizedRegexAttribute () : base(Validations.RegexExpression)
  >     {
  >
  >     }
  >
  >     public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
  >     {
  >         return base.FormatErrorMessage(ValidationStrings.ErrorMessage);
  >     }
  > }
  > ```
- Option 2:

> ```
> public class EmailAddressAttribute :ValidationAttribute {
> public EmailAddressAttribute()
> {
>
> }
>
> public override bool IsValid(object value)
> {
>     Regex regex = new Regex(Validations.RegexExpression);
>     return regex.IsMatch(value.ToString());
> }
>
> public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
> {
>     return base.FormatErrorMessage(ValidationStrings.ErrorMessage);
> } }
> ```

than you will use it like this:

```
[LocalizedRegexAttribute]
public string PostalCode { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. regExpValforPostal_ValidationExpression \d{5}(-\d{4})? for US ZipCode

Comment: I've added another option, simply implementing the regex by yourself.